# excel selection changed for specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I searched a lot for an answer for my problem, but couldn't find anything that helped me.

I want to use Worksheet_SelectionChange` for a specific worksheet. This specific worksheet I want to define in code.

Example (this example makes no sense, I know, but it is the best way to show my problem):

I have three worksheets in my workbook: `ws1`, `ws2`, `ws3`.

`ws1` and `ws3` are empty, `ws2` has some values. When I open the workbook, I search which worksheet is not empty. This works so far.

Now that I found which worksheet is not empty, I want to set the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` for this worksheet.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to show the (first) empty sheet? if so, when you identify your empty sheet, you can just `Activate` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in the THISWORKBOOK Code area

This is give you the name of the sheet if the cells are not empty, when you select a cell in that sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sh.Cells) <> 0 Then

        MsgBox Sh.Name & " is not blank"

        With Sh
            '~~> Insert code here which you want to run for that sheet
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If you do not want to go this way then you will have to inject the code in the relevant sheet code area. Injecting code in the sheet code area has been discussed many times here in SO

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly that what I was searching for